# Switching from Frontend (Javascript) to Go Backend Engineer

Tags: career-development, software-development, career-switch

I have been predominantly a full stack developer more on the frontend  using the javascript stack (React, Node, Typescript), however, I am being hired for a job that will focus more on the backend using Golang, of which I have little experience of.

I want to hit the ground running before I start my new role, and wanted to know besides getting more familiar with the Golang syntax, what else should I focus on learning? Some kind of road map or feedback from people with a similar situation would be appreciated.

Comment: @LaurentS. I am still employed with my current company but need to hand in my notice. I think because I have full stack experience that helped and I did my coding tests in Javascript. Will Join the new company in about 2 months.

Answer (score 5):

If you are full stack, and you've not being doing backend work; then please stop calling yourself fullstack.  You're a front end developer, and there is a huge demand for skilled ones.

Now that you're going to do golang development on the backend, it seems your new employer is asking for skills you fear you might not have.  If you really do have these skills, then consider that there is a thing called "Imposter Syndrome" where skilled people realize how much they don't know, so they discount what they do know.  If you're not an imposter, and you really don't know; then you can either try to learn what you need or confess that you've been lying to your future employer.

My recommendation is that in future employment situations; you trust your knowledge and you don't overextend yourself.  I don't know you; so, I can't be sure how to direct you to success.

Answer (score 0):

As a full-stack developer (standard front end stuff, started with HTML/CSS, JS), worked with lots of frameworks, PHP, Python, Java, .NET, I would suggest you stop and think if you know anything about backend before taking on the job.

The front end is like the interior decorator. Things do need to work, and things do need to not fall apart, but generally, you are probably not as rigorously held to standards. You don't need to worry about electrical code, plumbing code, foundation, water level, etc.

The structural engineer is more like the backend developer. There are standards and compliance they need to deal with. The house has to meet code, there are legal ramifications for not meeting code.

As a backend developer, you need to know about security, scalability, and lots of other "boring" things. You'll probably be dealing with a lot more database related issues, and need to understand what can and cannot be done client side (client vs server side encryption, critical data validation like credit cards, passwords, etc).

Failures as a front-end developer will result in ugly looking websites. Failures as a back-end developer can land you in jail. You need to clearly know what legal liabilities you take on with the back-end role before you try to learn on the job. It's not impossible, but if you are the most knowledgeable person regarding security, and you know "nothing", that's very bad news for you.